# Plucking keys of nested objects with Lodash

Tags: javascript, nested, lodash

I have a structure like this:

```
      areas = {
        'sample-id': {
          title: 'Area 1',
          type: 'outdoor',
          boundaries: [
            'fm-86071.92984676428', 'fm-33663.81255808968',
            'fm-22124.724922206497', 'fm-98002.82095021005'
          ]
        },
        'sample-id-2': {
          title: 'Area 2',
          type: 'meetingroom',
          boundaries: [
            'fm-39517.47084731459', 'fm-79087.74683350614',
            'fm-39153.28644344014', 'fm-38873.63204123109',
            'fm-67952.07827771583', 'fm-53210.58304837807',
          ]
        }
      };
```

I need to obtain an array consisting of all `title` keys of each area, i.e., required output = `['Area 1', 'Area 2']`.
I found that `_.pluck` has been removed in favor of `_.map`, but using

```
_.map(areas, 'title')
```

..needs areas to be an array.
I also think that converting the object into an array using `_.values` and then using `_.map` ought to work, but is there any direct or preferred way ?
**EDIT:** I would also like to retain the order of keys
**EDIT 2:** Ok I forgot that there is **NO ORDER** for keys in objects, so leave that, I guess I'll use `Array.prototype.sort()`

Comment: The order of keys can not be retained. JavaScript objects do not preserve their order. If you want ordered keys you should use arrays instead of objects

Comment: Sorting the keys by name can be done however. Just like you mentioned

Comment: `_.map(areas, 'title')` works on objects as well. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash's `_.map()` works on objects as well:

```js
var areas = {"sample-id":{"title":"Area 1","type":"outdoor","boundaries":["fm-86071.92984676428","fm-33663.81255808968","fm-22124.724922206497","fm-98002.82095021005"]},"sample-id-2":{"title":"Area 2","type":"meetingroom","boundaries":["fm-39517.47084731459","fm-79087.74683350614","fm-39153.28644344014","fm-38873.63204123109","fm-67952.07827771583","fm-53210.58304837807"]}};

var result = _.map(areas, 'title');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I use

```
Object.keys(areas).map(k => areas[k].title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()`.

```js
areas = {
   'sample-id': {
     title: 'Area 1',
     type: 'outdoor',
     boundaries: [
       'fm-86071.92984676428', 'fm-33663.81255808968',
       'fm-22124.724922206497', 'fm-98002.82095021005'
     ]
   },
   'sample-id-2': {
     title: 'Area 2',
     type: 'meetingroom',
     boundaries: [
       'fm-39517.47084731459', 'fm-79087.74683350614',
       'fm-39153.28644344014', 'fm-38873.63204123109',
       'fm-67952.07827771583', 'fm-53210.58304837807',
     ]
   }
};
      
let returnValue = Object.values(areas).map(value => value.title)
console.log(returnValue)
```

Comment: If your concern is about the object order, it can not be done. Look at my comment on the question